# Pass object properties to generate an array of properties names

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class with quite a lot of properties and I need to post this class property names to a webservice.

Easy solution is just to create that array by hand, as in `new[] {"Id", "Name", "Date", "etc"}`.

But that's not fun, I would like to have intellisense support. So far I came up with creating an `enum` with all these properties, then having a helper function which takes array of these enums and calls .ToString() on each and adds to array. 
Problem - quite an useless enum and if my class gets updated, I would need to manualy sync that enum with class properties.

Ideal solution in my mind would be to have something like LINQ extension method, where I could pass properties, something like with Select - `ToPropertiesArray(x => {x.Id, X.Name, x.Date})`

Am I just crazy and this cannot be done and is just plainly stupid? Or a suggestion on how to pass property names with some kind of IntelliSense support?

Comment: **why**? You could get all the properties trough reflection, but what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Theres tons of requests and for each request I need to pass different properties. Not all of them, oh no. Just five from a hundred. And remembering all names is hard. So I would like intellisense suggesting names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class  MyClass
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string S{get;set;}
    public double D{get;set;}
}

public static string[] GetPropsNamesArray<T>(Expression<Func<T,Object>> expr)
{
    var t = GetObjectType(expr);
    var res = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Public)
        .Select(pi => pi.Name)
        .ToArray();
    return res;

}

public static Type GetObjectType<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
{
    if ((expr.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert) ||
        (expr.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.ConvertChecked))
    {
        var unary = expr.Body as UnaryExpression;
        if (unary != null)
            return unary.Operand.Type;
    }
    return expr.Body.Type;
}
```

and use:

```
var selectedPropsNames = GetPropsNamesArray<MyClass>(m => new {m.Id,m.S});
var allPropsNames = GetPropsNamesArray<MyClass>(m => m);
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's both hilarious and exactly what I wanted. :) Thanks!

Comment: @Lars totally agree about hilarious and glad it helped))

Answer (score 0):

As Lars said, you can use reflection. Using reflection in a method also gets you not having to rewrite when the properties collection changes. The beginning of a sample below iterates the public properties of an entity.

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo in properties)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't need ALL properties, I need specific properties.

Answer (score 0):

To have Intellisense support, you can use Expressions:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static List<string> ToPropertiesArray(params System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<object>>[] exprs)
    {
        return exprs.Select(expr => ((expr.Body as System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression).Operand
                                                as System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression).Member.Name)
                                    .ToList();
    }
}
```

with sample usage:

```
SomeClass cl = new SomeClass();
var types = Helper.ToPropertiesArray(() => cl.SomeField, () => cl.SomeOtherField);
```