# How do I simply create a collection of Linq Expressions as a parameter?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an abstract class that implements methods for creating a dictionary of property names and string values for the given child object.

I have an overload for this method accepting a `List<string>` as parameter, which then returns the names and values of those properties as a dictionary. For ease of use and type safety, however, I would like to implement Linq syntax. This is simple to do and use for a single property, but not so intuitive for a collection. I have included a test class's code below:

```
public abstract class TestBase<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> GetDictOfClass(List<string> propertyNames)
    {
        var tDictPropertyNames = propertyNames.Distinct().ToDictionary(e => e);
        return typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(e => tDictPropertyNames.ContainsKey(e.Name) && e.CanRead && e.CanWrite)
            .ToDictionary(e => e.Name, e => e.GetValue(this, null).ToString());
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> GetDictOfClass(Expression<Func<T, object>> propertyExpression)
    {
        var tMemberExpression = (MemberExpression)propertyExpression.Body;
        string tPropertyName = tMemberExpression.Member.Name;
        return GetDictOfClass(new List<string> { tPropertyName });
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> GetDictOfClass(List<Expression<Func<T, object>>> propertyNames)
    {
        var tPropertyNames = propertyNames.Select(e => 
        {
            var tMemberExpression = (MemberExpression)e.Body;                   
            return tMemberExpression.Member.Name;
        });
        return GetDictOfClass(tPropertyNames.Where(e => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e)).ToList());
    }
}

public class TestItem : TestBase<TestItem>
{
    public string StockCode { get; set; } = "12345";
    public double Price { get; set; } = 500;
    public int OnHand { get; set; } = 10;

    public void Test()
    {
        var nItem = new TestItem();

        // Test 1
        var tDict = nItem.GetDictOfClass(new List<string>
        {
            nameof(StockCode),
            nameof(Price),
            nameof(OnHand)
        });

        // Test 2
        tDict = nItem.GetDictOfClass(e => e.StockCode);

        // Test 3
        tDict = nItem.GetDictOfClass(new List<Expression<Func<TestItem, object>>>
        {
            e => e.StockCode,
            e => e.Price,
            e => e.OnHand
        });  
    }
}
```

As can be seen from the above example in Test1, the `List<string>` overload is reasonably easy to use, but depending on the user, not always type-safe or robust (miss-spelling of property names unless using nameof() etc.)

Unfortunately, the call to the overload accepting a `List<Expression<Func<T, object>>>` (Test 3) is not very elegant and can look intimidating (This code forms part of a tool that is used by some more junior developers in our company).

I would like to be able to call it as something like this:

```
var tDict = TestItem.GetDictOfClass(e => e.StockCode, e => e.Price, e => e.Onhand);
```

or even this:

```
var tDict = TestItem.GetDictOfClass(e => e.StockCode, e.Price, e.Onhand);
```

or something similarly simple, and not limited to how many overloads for Test2's implementation I write.

Should I abandon this line of thinking and be looking at something like a relay class or some factory model implementation instead? Any suggestions/pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> var tDict = TestItem.GetDictOfClass(e => e.StockCode, e => e.Price, e => e.Onhand);

This you should be able to achieve with `params` declaration:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetDictOfClass(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] propertyNames){}

// USAGE
tDict = nItem.GetDictOfClass1(e => e.StockCode, e => e.Price, e => e.OnHand);
```

> var tDict = TestItem.GetDictOfClass(e => e.StockCode, e.Price, e.Onhand);

this one can be turned into `var tDict = TestItem.GetDictOfClass(e => new {e.StockCode, e.Price, e.Onhand});`

And handling like this(using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20412285/2501279) answer to similar question):

```
public  Dictionary<string, string> GetDictOfClassViaNew<T>(Expression<Func<T, Object>> expr)
{
    var t = GetObjectType(expr);
    var propertyNames = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Select(pi => pi.Name)
        .ToList();
    return GetDictOfClass(propertyNames); // call your implementation with list
}

public static Type GetObjectType<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
{
    if ((expr.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert) ||
        (expr.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.ConvertChecked))
    {
        var unary = expr.Body as UnaryExpression;
        if (unary != null)
            return unary.Operand.Type;
    }
    return expr.Body.Type;
}

// USAGE
nItem.GetDictOfClassNew<TestItem>(i => new {i.OnHand, i.StockCode, i.Price}).Dump();
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the params was the silver bullet I have been missing, really appreciate it.

Comment: @TheonP glad it helped!

Answer (score 3):

You can change the method parameter to an array and use params.

```
public virtual void Load<TModel>(params Expression<Func<TModel, object>> [] properties) 
    {
        List<string> propertyNames = new List<string>();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            MemberExpression expression;
            if (property.Body is UnaryExpression)
                expression = ((UnaryExpression)property.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
            else
                expression = ((MemberExpression)property.Body);

            string propertyName = expression.Member.Name;
            propertyNames.Add(propertyName);
        }

        // do what you want here
    }
```

Then use as you want.

```
Load<TModel>(x => x.KeyField, x => x.Workspace);
```